# Context passed but ignored

Tags: sapui5

I'm creating an offline app.
When I create an item in a view, I'd like it to be printed in another view so I'm passing a context from a controller to another one thanks to the appView model :

**controller where it comes from :**

```
    onCreateContainer: function () {
        var oView = this.getView(),
            containerNumber = oView.byId("addContainerNumberInput").getValue(),
            containerWeight = oView.byId("addContainerWeightInput").getValue(),
            C = this.getView().getBindingContext();

        if (containerNumber !== "" && containerWeight !== "") {
            var d = this.getModel("appView").getData();

            if (!d["/LotSet('" + this.idParent + "')"]) {
                d["/LotSet('" + this.idParent + "')"] = {};
            }
            d["/LotSet('" + this.idParent + "')"][C.getPath()] = C;
            // this.getView().unbindObject();
            this._navBack();
        } else {
            var emptyInputFields = this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("emptyInputFields");

            MessageToast.show(emptyInputFields);
            return;
        }
    },
```

**Then I get it back in the second controller :**

```
var oTable = this.getView().byId("contenantsTable");
        var appView = this.getModel("appView");
        var oLot = appView.getData()["/LotSet('" + sObjectId + "')"];

        for (var key in oLot) {
            var I = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
                cells: [
                    sap.ui.xmlfragment(this.getView().getId(), "com.xxx.view.AjoutContenant", this)
                ]
            });
            I.setBindingContext(oLot[key]);
            oTable.addItem(I);
        }
```

The value of "oLot[key]" is good, it's the context I want to pass, unfortunately, it's completely ignored and the fragment prints elements from the initial context.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that your are modifying the data of the model directly. The model doesn't know that you are doing it so it is not propagating the changes to the bond components. So you have to either modify the model using [setProperty](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel/methods/setProperty) method, or you have to call [updateBindings](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.ClientModel/methods/updateBindings) method after you are done modifying the data.

Comment: the way @lionelC is accessing it it be: this.getModel("appView").setData(d, false); the change the false to true if you want to merge data instead of replacing it

Comment: @Erch it kind of works but in order to avoid to print it many times I use a "oTable.removeAllItems();" in the _ObjectMatched method and a "this.getView().unbindElement();" (maybe wrong place though) to avoid to print empty items in the previous page.
Then I'm back at start, an item which ignores the passed context is printed.

Comment: if you want to ignore epmty items u proberly dont want to use unbind, you should do smth in the sence of: if ( item === null ) { return },